# Performing Date Math on Hive Partition Columns

Tags: hive, presto, amazon-athena

My data is partitioned by day in the standard Hive format:

```
/year=2020/month=10/day=01
/year=2020/month=10/day=02
/year=2020/month=10/day=03
/year=2020/month=10/day=04
...
```

I want to query all data from the last 60 days, using Amazon Athena (IE: Presto).  I want this query to use the partitioned columns (`year`, `month`, `day`) so that only the necessary partition files are scanned.  Assuming I can't change the file partition format, what is the best approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `year`, `month`, `day` as the partition keys for the table. You can have a single partition key called `date` and add the partitions like this:

```
ALTER TABLE the_table ADD
PARTITION (`date` = '2020-10-01') LOCATION 's3://the-bucket/data/year=2020/month=10/day=01'
PARTITION (`date` = '2020-10-02') LOCATION 's3://the-bucket/data/year=2020/month=10/day=02'
...
```

With this setup you can even set the type of the partition key to `date`:

```
PARTITIONED BY (`date` date)
```

Now you have a table with a `date` column typed as a `DATE`, and you can use any of the [date and time functions](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html) to do calculations on it.

What you won't be able to do with this setup is use `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` to load partitions, but you really shouldn't do that anyway – it's extremely slow and inefficient and really something you only do when you have a couple of partitions to load into a new table.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to that proposed by Theo, is to use the following syntax, e.g.:

```
select ... from my_table where year||month||day between '2020630' and '20201010'
```

this works when the format for the columns `year`, `month` and `day` are string. It's particularly useful to query across months.